# VMWare shared folder inaccessible with Administrator account

Tags: administrator, vmware-player, shared-folders

VMWare Player runs a Windows 10 VM.
I've shared a folder with this VM, setting "*​Map as network drive in Windows guest*" to `TRUE`.

I need to type a command (npm) as Administrator in the shared folder from the guest.
However, there's a problem:

As lambda user:

```
net use
New connections will be remembered.

Status       Local     Remote                    Network
------------------------------------------------------------------------
             Z:        \\vmware-host\Shared Folders
                                                 Dossiers partagés VMware
The command completed successfully.
```

As Administrator:

```
net use
New connections will be remembered.

There are no entries in the list.
```

The Administrator account does not seem to know about the VMWare shared folder.
Is there a way to access the shared folder as Administrator?

Comment: The Administrator user context doesn't know about the lambda user context's maps, you'll have to map it again in the Administrator context (open command prompt as Admin, run `net use Z: \\vmware-host\Shared Folders`).

Comment: net use Z: \\vmware-host\Shared Folders
Z: has a remembered connection to \\vmware-host\Shared Folders. Do you want to overwrite the remembered connection? (Y/N) [Y]: y
System error 67 has occurred.

The network name cannot be found.

Should I have answered _No_ ?

Comment: Typed net use Z: "\\vmware-host\Shared Folders" (with quotes) and it worked.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So, as said in the comments, typing `net use Z: "\\vmware-host\Shared Folders"` in an Administrator command prompt solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Create a scheduled task that has the following as an action:

```
%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /k start /min net use Z: "\\vmware-host\Shared Folders"
```

Now you should be able to access the folder.